# entry with new window

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want a new window appearing with simple entry to put one line of text and button ok to set value of variable. When I use simple entry command, it appear in my main window. I need something like tk_dialog with option to put text to some variable. Is there any predefined tk_* function?

Comment: There isn't a predefined dialog for that. Since it isn't really that much code, nobody's ever go around to doing one, particularly since it usually needs a bit of extra customisation specific to a particular use case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create another window with tk toplevel command

```
% set top [toplevel .top]
.top
% focus $top
% grab $top
% set entryBox [entry $top.ent -textvariable x]
.top.ent
% pack $entryBox
% set btn [button $top.btn -text "Click Me"]
.top.btn
% pack $btn
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedure:

```
proc entrybox varName {
    set top [toplevel .top[clock seconds]]
    entry $top.eb -textvariable $varName
    button $top.bu -command [list incr ${top}done] -text OK
    pack {*}[winfo children $top]
    vwait ::${top}done
    unset -nocomplain ::${top}done
    destroy $top
}
```

when given a global or fully qualified name, creates a new toplevel dialog with an entry and a button. It waits for the button to be clicked and then destroys the toplevel dialog. The text in the entrybox remains in the variable.

Documentation:
[button (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/button.htm),
[clock](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm),
[destroy](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/destroy.htm),
[entry (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/entry.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[pack](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[toplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/toplevel.htm),
[unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm),
[vwait](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/vwait.htm),
[winfo](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/winfo.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)